# Kivy FileChooser does not work as an apk on some android phone ,How can i resolve it?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, filechooser

When I try to implement filechooser of kivy I have seen that it have worked well everywhere without Xaomi phone. When I go that page it shows an empty layout of filechooser. My code is given below:

```
Mypopup:
pos: (root.width * .025, root.height *.020)
#size:(300,300)
auto_dismiss: True
size_hint:(1,1)
id:pop
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    FileChooserIconView:
        id: filechooser
        on_selection: pop.selected(filechooser.selection)
    Button:
        text:'upload'
        size_hint_x:.7
        size_hint_y:.1
        background_color:1,1,1,1
        on_release:pop.dismiss
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
        on_press: app.next_screen('resource/tima/know_myself/my_information')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with path `/storage/emulated/0/`

As an example, add it to your `.kv` file like this:

```
#:import platform kivy.utils.platform

FileChooserListView:
    rootpath: '/storage/emulated/0/' if platform == 'android' else '/'
```

Comment: For me I also needed to add permissions:
`from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission`
`request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])`


Per documentations:
https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions

Answer (score 1):

I've been messing with a similar problem for hours now. What I found is that you have to set rootpath to `/storage/emulated/0/`. It's not enough to set path only, because if rootpath is left `None` (by default), it gives user the option to navigate out of `/storage/emulated/0/`. When only path was set, I was getting permission denied errors even though I had the read/write permissions, and `filechooser` didn't display anything.

Maybe it should have been obvious, but it wasn't for me...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in xperia XA phone.
I have found out that is probably a permission issue.

I found that out by setting the default path of the file chooser to the folder of the app, in my case the folder was: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files" and then it worked perfectly but if i try to go out of that folder it doesn't work anymore, even if I requested all the permissions that are necessary (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) to do so.

So if you haven't tried yet try requesting the permissions above, or for a test sake give the permissions to the app manually going in the settings of your android.

If that does't help try setting the default path to the path that your app has access in android:

```
   `FileChooserListView:
        path: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files"`
```

And see if that solves the problem of being empty.

The path is usually "/data/data/name.of.your.package" but if that doesn't work try run the commands(with app installed in your phone already and the phone connected to USB):

```
adb shell
pm list packages
```

Find the package name of your app and then:

```
run-as package.name
pwd
```

copy the path that shows up.

I hope that helps.